# GroupBy only one field, not all the fields I have in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am working with the next table:

```
**ID    Value   Data**
1   30  25/4
1   20  26/4
1   20  27/4
3   10  25/4
4   20  26/4
5   30  26/4
```

And I need to query the table and have the next result:

```
**ID    Value   Data**
1   70  "Any value, can be 25/4, 26/4 or 27/4"
3   10  25/4
4   20  26/4
5   30  26/4
```

I try to query using GroupBy, but If add the all fields (ID, Value and Data) the result returns the 1st table. And, if I only GroupBy field ID, I am having the next error:

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Can anyone help about how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `min()` or `max()`:

```
select id, sum(value), min(data)
from t
group by id;
```

If you actually want a random value, you can use:

```
select id, sum(value),
       min(data) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_random.random)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have some null ID, the query sum the values. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @RenéFontan . . . You can add `where id is not null`.

Comment: Gordon, I want to show the null ID but I don´t want to sum them.

Comment: @RenéFontan . . . If `sum(case when id is not null then value end)` doesn't answer the question, you should ask as a new *question*, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ok, open a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345735/group-by-id-except-the-null-records

Answer (score 2):

We could arbitrarily take the minimum `Data` value in each `ID` group:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Value) AS Value, MIN(Data) AS Data
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```