# Group by ID except the NULL records

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am working with the next table:

```
**ID    Value   Data**
1        30     25/4
1        20     26/4
1        20     27/4
3        10     25/4
4        20     26/4
5        30     26/4
NULL     50     25/4
NULL     10     26/4
```

And I need to query the table and have the next result:

```
**ID    Value   Data**
1        70     25/4
3        10     25/4
4        20     26/4
5        30     26/4
NULL     50     25/4
NULL     10     26/4
```

I have this query:

```
select id, sum(value), min(data)
from t
group by id;
```

But the query sums the NULL IDs

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is probably `union all`:

```
select id, sum(value), min(data)
from t
where id is not null
group by id
union all
select id, value, data
from t
where id is null;
```